# Regex for matching XX/YY strings but not XX/YY/ZZ strings

Tags: python, regex

I would like to try and match text that is in the form of

```
<some digits>/<some digits>
```

, but NOT

```
<some digits>/<some digits>/<some digits>
```

As an example, if the text is

```
01/21
```

or

```
1/21
```

I would like to match those, but not

```
1995/01/01
```

or

```
5/12/92
```

The background for this is that I am using Duckling to detect dates, and it detects dates like "12/21", but classifies this as MM/DD, whereas I want it to treat it as YY/MM, so I would like to correct these detections.

How would I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
(?<!\d)(?<!\d/)\d+/\d+(?!/?\d)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/kwxxtw/2).

**Explanation**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /?                       '/' (optional (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! I was missing the last (?!/?\d) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}`.
You can try your regular expressions here: https://regex101.com

Comment: I tried this with "1995/03/11" and it returned "95/03", but I don't want it to return anything.